# Mac OS Audio Frameworks

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, audiounit

There are CoreAudio.framework; CoreAudioKit.framework; AudioUnit.framework; AudioToolbox.framework.

I most care about AudioUnit and AudioToolbox; It seems that AudioUnit is the most low level, AUGraph is based on AudioUnit.

Because AUGraph resides in AudioToolbox.framework, so I would expect AudioToolbox.framework to be dependent on AudioUnit.framework. However, when I used otool -L to check the dependency, it is totally the other way, that is: AudioUnit depends on AudioToolbox.

This confused me.

Is there anyone who can explain the four Audio frameworks in mac OS?

Comment: "Is there anyone who can explain the four Audio frameworks in mac OS?" - probably only their creator (but even that's not sure...)

Comment: Is your question about why the frameworks are organized this way or what the function of each framework is?